# Select more than one property using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say we have a `Line` class defined by `Point startPoint` and `Point endPoint`.

If I have list of these lines, how can I extract all the points in them into one `List<Point>` using **LINQ**.

This is what I have so far:

```
IList<Point> points1 = lines.Select(o => o.StartPoint).ToList();
IList<Point> points2 = lines.Select(o => o.EndPoint).ToList();

IList<Point> points = points1.Concat(points2).ToList();
```

Comment: and what is ap problem with your solution?

Comment: I wondered if there is one line cleaner solution.

Comment: You can't use `Concat` if `StartPoint` & `EndPoint` are different types.

Comment: @RahulSingh thery are in this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a shorter way, you can do something like this:

```
var points = lines.SelectMany(l => new[] { l.StartPoint, l.EndPoint }).ToList();
```

However, your current code is debateably more readable, but more importantly, does not create an array for each `line` you iterate.

However, you don't need to invoke `ToList()` for each set, you can simply write:

```
var points = lines.Select(l => l.StartPoint).Concat(lines.Select(l => l.EndPoint)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a few different ways. One is to use `Tuple<Point, Point>` :

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<Point, Point>> r = lines.Select(l => new Tuple<Point, Point>(l.StartPoint, l.EndPoint));
```

To access these then you have to keep in mind that `StartPoint` would be `Item1` and `EndPoint` will be `Item2` :

```
foreach ( Tuple<Point, Point> se in r )
{
    var start = se.Item1;
    var end   = se.Item2;
}
```

Another one could be to make an array of 2 elements each :

```
IEnumerable<Point[]> r = lines.Select(l => new Point[2]{ l.StartPoint, l.EndPoint });
```

To access these you have to keep in mind that index `0` contains your `StartPoint` and index `1` contains your `EndPoint` :

```
foreach( Point[] parr in r )
{
    if( parr.Length == 2 )
    {
        var start = parr[0];
        var end   = parr[1];
    }
}
```

You can always create a flat model containing only these two properties and then just cast/create it in the `Select`.

There are dozens of ways to achieve what you want. The real question is what do you want to do with this result later.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is the closer you can get to it. If you don't want to enumerate twice the list you should go for a Foreach/Map approach:

```
var points = new List<Point>();

lines.Map(line =>
{
     points.Add(line.startPoint);
     points.Add(line.EndPoint);
 } );
```

If you don't want to use Concat you can use Union:

```
lines.Select(o => o.StartPoint).Union(lines.Select(o => o.EndPoint)).ToList();
```